# C++: access values of 2D array being passed as parameter/pointer in function

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, ctypes

I am trying to access values of a 2D array initially passed as an array of pointers in the function. Additionally I would like this function to return a 2D array with the values I have accessed and worked on.

I understand the concept of pointer, however I have trouble with the double pointer concept of 2D arrays. If I understand correctly, iterating over the first dimension of the array points to a position in the memory of the computer, which itself points to another position of the memory in the computer where the value is. This 2 pointing process represents the 2D.

Now, in my code, I don't manage to access the values of this second pointer and I don't understand why.

```
extern "C" double cfun(double **indatav, int rows, int cols)
{

    double* *outdatav = new double*[rows];
    for (int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        outdatav[i] = new double*[cols];
        }

    for (int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < cols; j++){
            outdatav[i][j] = indatav[i][j];
            }
        }
    return outdatav;
}
```

The code above is called through ctypes in Python and therefore it has this `extern...` However the equivalent in `C++` would just consist in removing this `extern "C"`
I have spent quite some time now on this problem and I don't think I will be able to solve it alone so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `*indata[i][j]` is not valid.  `intdatav[i]` IS a pointer and points to the start of row I.  Just use `outdatav[i][j] = indatav[i][j];`

Comment: Note that you'll also have to free all those pointers. If you're going to access this func from *Python* only I thought about a workaround that would not require *Python* code to call the deallocation func. I was preparing it for one of the 2 question you deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems wrong memory allocation in double pointer

```
double* *outdatav = new double*[rows];
for (int i=0; i < rows; i++){
    // outdatav[i] = new double*[cols]; // <- typo here
    outfatav[i] = new double [cols]; // <- replace with this
}
```

ADD

the return type of the function is not matched with the returned variable, so need to revise the return type to `double**`

```
extern "C" double** cfun(double **indatav, int rows, int cols)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it still doesn't entirely solve my problem (see edit)

Comment: for `*indatav[i][j];`, already `indatav[i][j]` points to the value (type as double), not an address

Answer (score 1):

extern "C" double cfun(double **indatav, int rows, int cols)

```
{

    double**outdatav = new double*[rows];
    for (int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        outdatav[i] = new double[cols];
        }

    for (int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < cols; j++){
            outdatav[i][j] = indatav[i][j];
            }
        }
    return outdatav;
}
```

This will work properly now.

```
 outdatav[i] = new double[cols];
```

In this line of code, you were assigning an array of pointers to a pointer. Instead, you have to assign array to each pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and edit, but it still doesn't entirely solve my problem because I want outdatav to be a matrix of values, and not pointers to pointers.

Comment: no problem at all :).. The above code solved your problem right?

Comment: Well the code now works correctly according to your recommendations, which was the question of this thread. However, I am not able to do what I want but I am not sure where does the problem come from, if it's from Python or from C++, so therefore I did another thread on the subject where I am detailing more precisely what exactly my problem is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150201/ctypes-return-values-in-2d-numpy-array-from-c-function

Comment: @JoachimBsh: Note: It takes an user to have *10k+* reputation in order to be able to view deleted posts.